# Read and Write to the same file in Perl

Tags: perl, file-handling

This is in continuation with this ->[Read and Write to a file in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633743/read-and-write-to-a-file-in-perl) question.

The following code worked perfectly fine for reading and writing to the same file:

```
use Tie::File;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = "out.txt";
my @array;
tie @array, 'Tie::File', $filename
    or die "can't tie file \"$filename\": $!";

for my $line (@array) {

    $line = "<$line>";
}
untie @array;
```

But when I did the following the changes were not reflected in the file :

```
use Tie::File;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = "out.txt";
my @array;
tie @array, 'Tie::File', $filename
    or die "can't tie file \"$filename\": $!";

my $len = @array;
for ($i = 0; $i < $len ; $i++) {

    $line = $array[$i];
    $line = "<$line>";     
}
untie @array;
```

Can someone help me with this problem ?
Yes I know I can use the for loop above, knowing this may help me solve some other problems too.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first snippet, you're modifying the elements of `@array` (via the alias `$line`).

In the second, you're not modifying any elements of `@array`. Change

```
$line = $array[$i];
$line = "<$line>";
```

to

```
$line = $array[$i];
$line = "<$line>";
$array[$i] = $line;
```

or simply

```
$array[$i] = "<$array[$i]>";
```

Note that using Tie::File is an awful way to do what you are doing.