# how to use a file handle opened in the main block inside a function?

Tags: perl

I have opened a file in Perl

```
open(HANDLE,$inputfile)
```

Now, I want to use this `HANDLE` inside a function and write to the same file. How can I do that?

I am new to Perl so can anyone help me out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read and Write to a file in perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633743/read-and-write-to-a-file-in-perl)

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you don't want to use package filehandles (which lack a sigil); lexical filehandles (which start with a `$`) are much less prone to error, and are definitely easier to pass to subroutines:

```
use autodie; # Check everything succeeds automatically.

open(my $fh, '<', $inputfile);

some_function($fh);

sub some_function {
    my ($filehandle) = @_;   # This was `$fh` from above

    print {$filehandle} "Hello World!\n";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It is very simple to writing in file.
`HANDLE` is the file descriptor of file 
so for writing you need to use `print` command.

> print HANDLE "what you want to write"

this print will write comment to that file.

Comment: Yes I know that but I have created this handle at the starting of the code now I am calling a function and I want to use that handle inside that function to start writing inside the file from where I ended so can I use the same handle or I need to pass it to that function

Comment: Yes you need to pass the HANDLER to other function or subroutine.
For detail you can see this link..
http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=636998